# Docker: attach to a specific bash

Tags: linux, docker

Lets say I have a container running and I do

```
docker exec -ti container-id /bin/bash
```

Then I detach from this container and want to attach again

If I do this

```
docker attach container-id
```

I wont go back to that bash that I created. Instead I will go to the main process.

How can I attach to that bash again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  While the [`docker exec` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#usage) suggests it supports the same "detach" key sequence as `docker run`, the exec'd process doesn't have any Docker-level identity (beyond its host and container pids) and there's no way to re-attach to that shell.

(In the Docker API, ["exec instance" is an actual object](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#tag/Exec) so this isn't technically impossible; the CLI just has no support for it.)

The workflow you're describing sounds more like what you'd run with `screen` or `tmux` in a virtual machine.

Comment: It worked with tmux
The easiest way is to run docker exec inside a tmux named session

Answer (score 0):

I have one container and I have started it using, and checked the `pid` of `/bin/bash`

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-153 centos]# docker exec -ti 78c2e4a46b58 /bin/bash
root@78c2e4a46b58:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 bash
root        10     0  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        20    10  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Now I detach from container using `CTR+p and CTR+q` sequence and container is detached.

Now I reattach using the container id and I see the same `pid` of `/bin/bash`

```
root@78c2e4a46b58:/# [root@ip-10-0-1-153 centos]# docker attach 78c2e4a46b58
root@78c2e4a46b58:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 bash
root        10     0  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        21     1  0 03:25 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
root@78c2e4a46b58:/#
```

I hope you're using `CTR+p CTR+q` sequence to detach from the container.